# bitcoind -daemon command error

Tags: full-node

Im trying to open bitcoin core withthe command
bitcoind -daemon

My node is working perfectly with GUI
But When trying to run bitcoind -daemon

error: Could not connect to the server
Make sure the bitcoind server is running and that you are connecting to the correct RPC port.

---

Any help?
For some reason its showing i am in Prune mode?
Im not sure if this is the cause of the error if so please instruct me to fix this
Cheers

Comment: You should be using bitcoin-cli to connect to bitcoind. Can you also post your `debug.log`  file?

Comment: I have changed the bitcoin.conf file to prune=0 to correct the error tho now im getting this error trying to restard of prune mode. 

You need to rebuild the database using -reindex to go back to unpruned mode.  This will redownload the entire blockchain.
Please restart with -reindex or -reindex-chainstate to recover.
Error: Error opening block database



Any help here ?

Comment: Are you trying to run the GUI and `bitcoind` at the same time? How are you running the RPC client? Is the GUI running with `-server`? There are a lot of relevant details missing here.